Can phone numbers used for verification codes also be used for spam?
When a company asks for a phone number to send a verification code (example), are they allowed by law to also use that number for spam, or sell that number to another company? Or are there some laws preventing this kind of misuse. I'm mostly interested in the United States.

I doubt very much there's any law specific to verification codes. I think the law against junk calls specifically excludes calls to existing customers.

AFAIK, there's no general law against junk calls other than the National Do-Not-Call list. If your number is on that list, and whoever buys your number from the company calls you, they would be violating that law.

@Barmar thanks, yes verification codes could be included / a special case / a subset of a more generic law.

I don't think the company that sold your number would have any liability, though. The US doesn't have privacy laws regarding phone numbers.

european-union and other gdpr-affected countries:
Personal data like the phone number may only be used with consent or another legal basis, for the purposes outlined in the consent. Consent must be specific, informed, and granted separately on separable uses. So if the company wants to send "advertisements" to a verification number or "sell it to advertisers," there needs to be a specific check box to that effect which the customer may leave unchecked.
But the performance of a contract is another possible legal basis for using the number. A company with "creative" legal and compliance departments might try to argue that what you call "spam" is not spam at all, but rather part of their duties in their contract with you. Taking them to court over that is probably best done with the help of consumer rights advocates, not alone.
